# Unrecognized element 'readerQuotas' on BasicHttpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf, readerquotas

I have a problem with my WCF service config, I get the error:
"The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message ....
the maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded....."

So after searching at google  i found that i need to set this line in my config file :

```
<readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
```

but when i add it to the web.config, i get the error :

Unrecognized element 'readerQuotas'

what shall i do?!

my binding :

```
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Stream_Binding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed" messageEncoding="Mtom"/>
<readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
</basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

readerQuotas node needs to be inside of binding